# Mongoose schema for location in app created with @react-google-maps/api

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

What should the mongoose schema look like for a part of my dataset that looks like this:
"location": {
"lat": 59.369761,
"lng": 13.4867216
},

The format above is chosen to match @react-google-maps/api when used it as in this tutorial https://medium.com/@allynak/how-to-use-google-map-api-in-react-app-edb59f64ac9d

I have tried these below without success (either the app breaks or MongoDB skips key location when seeding the database.

```
location: {
    type: {
      type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
      type: Schema.Types.Decimal128 }
  }
 location: {
    type: {
      type: Decimal128,
      type: Decimal128 }
  }
 location: {
    type: {
      type: mongoose.Decimal128,
      type: mongoose.Decimal128 }
  }
 location: {
    type: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
      type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 }
  }
  location: {
    type: {
      type: Number,
      type: Number }
  }
location: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
      type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works
location: { type: Object }